# SAP NetWeaver Administrator Console For Monitoring

Tags: netweaver

I have to test the performance of SAP SSO Server. I have been granted the admin access to use SAP NetWeaver Administrator Console. I see many monitoring options on the console also.

Do I need to configure the SAP SSO Server in SAP NetWeaver Admin Console to monitor it?

Comment: As far as I know, you need. Always better to have it.

Comment: @Atul Is it possible to enable SAP NWA Console on same server which we have to monitor? because i have to monitor server "my_server" and i am accessing the SAP Net Weaver Administrator Console on same server like https:myserver:port/nwa